# Mint: Ram not running up to speed

Tags: memory, bios, linux-mint

[Here is my RAM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104339), and [here is my motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128521).  The Ram is rated to 1600 MHz, and the motherboard supports that speed.

However, according to `sudo dmidecode --type 17`, The chips are only running at 1333 MHz:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A0
    Bank Locator: Bank0/1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1
    Bank Locator: Bank2/3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A2
    Bank Locator: Bank4/5
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0029
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A3
    Bank Locator: Bank6/7
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:
```

Is this a problem with my BIOS, or with my operating system?  Either way, how can I get my RAM running at full speed?

Comment: Yes, most likely you haven't set the correct clock speed for the RAM in your BIOS. How this is done is BIOS specific but if you look around then the setting you need shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: So I found it in the BIOS (I think) and set it 1600, but linux still says 1333 MHZ

Comment: So when i booted after changing the BIOS, it said "system failed to boot due to overclocking" then reverted to 1333 MHz

Comment: This is VERY common. The problem is that the rating on memory is really just an estimate. A LOT of memory will not actually work at the reported speed. I'm guessing that is the case here. The safe thing to do is to leave it at 1333 and that'll work great. If you really want the 1600 speeds then you're probably going to need to tweak it. Here is some information on that http://www.techradar.com/us/news/computing-components/upgrades/how-to-overclock-your-ram-1030286 . Be warned however that doing this could lead to destruction of the RAM\CPU\Mobo and WILL cause the RAM to have a shorter life.

Comment: Thanks. Noted. I probably wont do anything until i can afford to have the machine get fried

Comment: The RAM rating is a maximum capability, not a fixed requirement.  The system has a design speed that it operates at.  Putting in RAM capable of handling a higher speed doesn't change what the system runs at.